# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning Ruby on Rails Tutorial, I have finished the chapter 7 and it works well,  but come across 25 failures/errors like the following:

User 
     Failure/Error: @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18:in `new'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18:in`block (2 levels) in '

This is the users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 27):

You can check to see if `db/test.sqlite3` is empty. In that case, run `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: In Rails 3.2 or latest just execute: rake db:test:prepare